# Byte Alignment in Files

Tags: file, data-structures, alignment, byte

I've been looking at file formats and information on byte alignment in files is hard to come by.  I can find information on memory byte alignment ("Data Structure Alignment"), but that's a different matter.

In setting up a standard format, is there an optimal way to align bytes in a file that is good or even necessary for various systems?  This is not for one data type, but for many.  Is 2-byte alignment sufficient, or is it really even necessary?  What about 4-byte alignment?  How well will a 32-bit or 64-bit system handle this?

Answer (score 4):

When working with binary data, very often you'll just write memory directly to the file. In that case, data in the file is aligned exactly as it is in memory. This has the advantage of not requiring any intermediate steps when reading the information back into your memory data structures. It does use a bit more disk space than absolutely required if you were to eliminate the alignment, but typically not a lot of space.

You have to be careful, though, if you'll be reading that data from other programs. They have to be written to take the padding bytes into account. For example if you have this structure:

```
struct foo
{
    int a;
    char b;
    int c;
}
```

And you tell it to align on 32-bit boundaries, your memory (and therefore disk) layout will be:

```
4 bytes - a
1 byte - b
3 bytes - padding
4 bytes - c
```

If the other program isn't written to take that into account and instead assumes byte alignment, it'll try to read `c` from the four bytes immediately following `b`. The result, as you can imagine, wouldn't be good.

When I'm working with binary data, I usually just write the data to the file, ignoring the typically small amount of "waste" that's due to data alignment.

Comment: Thanks, Jim.  I'm looking for what could be used for a standard (rather just dumping data structures) and is reasonably easy to read on different systems provided they follow the standard.  I guess I could have been clearer in my question....

Comment: @someprogrammer: Then I would suggest writing the data with no padding. You have bigger problems like how to represent strings, whether to store multi-byte values in big endian or little endian format, how to represent dates, etc. Adding the concept of alignment or padding would confuse things further and gain you nothing.

Comment: This answer misses the *alignment* part of this question.  If you write an array (padding and all), should this data be written at an aligned possition, to 2/4/8... what are the tradeoffs here? - Note that I've seen formats that are *not* memory dumps - writing at 4 bytes of alignment, so assume there is a good reason to do this. (At a guess - faster `memcpy` from aligned locations when loading?)

Comment: @ideasman42: Typically if you're writing binary data directly to the file, then if the data is aligned then it will be aligned in the file. Unless you're writing some of the data from aligned structures and other parts of it from non-aligned data. Certainly this can happen in the case of strings. There might be some small performance gain if you do the alignment. But typically the time you spend in `memcpy` and other such functions is so small compared to the cost of getting data from the drive that such optimizations result in minimal performance gains.

Comment: Do I need to alocate an aligned memory storage when reading data? It seems to be important, otherwise all these alignments wouldn't work in the memory. Because an in-file alignment is relative to its base, but when the file is loaded to the memory, the base should be aligned relative to the beginning of the virtual memory, isn't?